# Powershell insert default registry name without quotes

Tags: powershell, registrykey

I'm trying to add an application in the context menu using Powershell.
When I'm using the command below to add the registry Expandable String, the name Default aka @ is inserted between quotes but it should be without.

`[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("$hcrAPP\shell\$flyout\command", "@", "$appPath\$appVer\app\bin\app.exe $userDir\$app", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)`

Result:
`"@"=hex(2):43,00,3a,...`

Expected Result:
`@=hex(2):43,00,3a,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note
>
> A registry key can have one value that is not associated with any
>   name. When this unnamed value is displayed in the registry editor, the
>   string "(Default)" appears instead of a name. To set this unnamed
>   value, specify either null or the empty string ("") for name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8